# Azure Sentinel Sample data CSV

Tags: azure, azure-sentinel

I have a sentinel instance running in azure but not enough data to test the full functionality of sentinel.
Doing some research I came across with azure sentinel GitHub:

https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Sentinel/tree/master/Sample%20Data

This has enough sample data for testing and getting my hands dirty and try to understand the full power of sentinel and how to leverage it. But I was wondering if there is a way or option about how to get those csv file (import) into sentinel portal.

I hope my question is clear and if not please don't not hesitate to ask more details.

Thank you so much for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import them as custom logs:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/agents/data-sources-custom-logs#define-a-custom-log

Additionally, check out the "Training Lab" solution in Content Hub in the Sentinel console. Installing this will populate data.